# How to use InfoPath Forms with SharePoint Desinger 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, custom-form

I want to use InfoPath forms for my New, Edit and Display Form.
I know how to do this with SharePoint Designer 2010, but I don't know how to do it with SharePoint Designer 2013.

When I click 'new item' I get the Edit form by default. How can I change that? 
In SPD 2010 it was open form -> right click -> properties -> Default view value

But I cannot find the field 'properties' in SPD 2013.

I got the explanation how to this all this here:
https://chanakyajayabalan.wordpress.com/2013/06/20/individual-newedit-and-display-forms-for-sharepoint-using-infopath-forms/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it manually. If you have published your Infopath form with multiple views, you can just navigate to each URL for New, Edit and Display item and change the view by editing the InfoPath webpart.

```
https://SharePointUrl/Lists/ListName/Item/newifs.aspx

https://SharePointUrl/Lists/ListName/Item//editifs.aspx

https://SharePointUrl/Lists/ListName/Item//displayifs.aspx
```

While there, just edit the page, then edit the InfoPath Form Web Part and select what view you want to display as default for the different actions (new item, edit item or display item), apply and save the page.

[image]

Comment: @Kim Glad it worked out. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have InfoPath, you can set the default form by doing the following:

- Just Open your New Form in browser.
- From the above ribbon select Customize forms.
- Now the form should be open via Infopath.
- Got to Page Design Tab, you should find now the view list with your 3 Forms.

  - New.
  - Edit.
  - Dispaly.

[image]

- Make sure you have select you new form > Click properties > Select the Set as default view check box, and then click OK.

[image]

If a form has only one view then it is automatically designated as the default view.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. 
The problem is that I need 3 views and not one default. If I edit the item I want the edit form, if I view the item I want the display form, ...